# SQL statement merge two rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, row

In the results of my sql-statement (SQL Server 2016) I would like to combine two rows with the same value in two columns ("study_id" and "study_start") into one row and keep the row with higest value in a third cell ("Id"). If any columns (i.e. "App_id" or "Date_arrival)  in the row with higest Id is NULL, then it should take the value from the row with the lowest "Id".

I get the result below:

```
Id      study_id    study_start  Code   Expl       Desc      Startmonth App_id  Date_arrival    Efter_op    Date_begin
167262    878899            954   4.1   udd.ord    Afbrudt   feb        86666   21-06-2012      N           17-08-2012
180537    878899            954     1   Afsluttet  Afsluttet feb        NULL    NULL            NULL        NULL
```

And I would like to get this result:

```
Id      study_id    study_start  Code   Expl       Desc      Startmonth App_id  Date_arrival    Efter_op    Date_begin
180537  878899       954            1   Afsluttet  Afsluttet feb        86666   21-06-2012      N           17-08-2012
```

My statement looks like this:

```
SELECT dbo.PopulationStam_V.ELEV_ID AS id,
dbo.PopulationStam_V.PERS_ID AS study_id,
dbo.STUDIESTARTER.STUDST_ID AS study_start, 
dbo.Optagelse_Studiestatus.AFGANGSARSAG AS Code, 
dbo.Optagelse_Studiestatus.KORT_BETEGNELSE AS Expl, 
ISNULL((CAST(dbo.Optagelse_Studiestatus.Studiestatus AS varchar(20))), 'Indskrevet') AS 'Desc',
dbo.STUDIESTARTER.OPTAG_START_MANED AS Startmonth,
dbo.ANSOGNINGER.ANSOG_ID as App_id,
dbo.ANSOGNINGER.ANKOMSTDATO AS Data_arrival',
dbo.ANSOGNINGER.EFTEROPTAG AS Efter_op,
dbo.ANSOGNINGER.STATUSDATO AS Date_begin
FROM dbo.INSTITUTIONER 
INNER JOIN dbo.PopulationStam_V 
ON dbo.INSTITUTIONER.INST_ID = dbo.PopulationStam_V.SEMI_ID 
LEFT JOIN dbo.ANSOGNINGER 
ON dbo.PopulationStam_V.ELEV_ID = dbo.ANSOGNINGER.ELEV_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.STUDIESTARTER 
ON dbo.PopulationStam_V.STUDST_ID_OPRINDELIG = dbo.STUDIESTARTER.STUDST_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.UDD_NAVNE_T 
ON dbo.PopulationStam_V.UDDA_ID = dbo.UDD_NAVNE_T.UDD_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.UDDANNELSER 
ON dbo.UDD_NAVNE_T.UDD_ID = dbo.UDDANNELSER.UDDA_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PERSONER 
ON dbo.PopulationStam_V.PERS_ID = dbo.PERSONER.PERS_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.POSTNR 
ON dbo.PERSONER.PONR_ID = dbo.POSTNR.PONR_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.KønAlleElevID_V 
ON dbo.PopulationStam_V.ELEV_ID = dbo.KønAlleElevID_V.ELEV_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Optagelse_Studiestatus 
ON dbo.PopulationStam_V.AFAR_ID = dbo.Optagelse_Studiestatus.AFAR_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.frafaldsmodel_adgangsgrundlag 
ON dbo.frafaldsmodel_adgangsgrundlag.ELEV_ID = dbo.PopulationStam_V.ELEV_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Optagelse_prioriteterUFM 
ON dbo.Optagelse_prioriteterUFM.cpr = dbo.PopulationStam_V.CPR_NR 
AND dbo.Optagelse_prioriteterUFM.Aar = dbo.frafaldsmodel_adgangsgrundlag.optagelsesaar 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.frafaldsmodel_stoettetabel_uddannelser AS fsu 
ON fsu.id_uddannelse = dbo.UDDANNELSER.UDDA_ID 
AND fsu.id_inst = dbo.INSTITUTIONER.INST_ID 
AND fsu.uddannelse_aar = dbo.frafaldsmodel_adgangsgrundlag.optagelsesaar
WHERE dbo.STUDIESTARTER.STUDIESTARTSDATO > '2012-03-01 00:00:00.000' 
AND (dbo.Optagelse_Studiestatus.AFGANGSARSAG IS NULL 
OR dbo.Optagelse_Studiestatus.AFGANGSARSAG NOT LIKE '2.7.4') 
AND (dbo.PopulationStam_V.INDSKRIVNINGSFORM = '1100' 
OR dbo.PopulationStam_V.INDSKRIVNINGSFORM = '1700') 
GROUP BY dbo.PopulationStam_V.ELEV_ID,
dbo.PopulationStam_V.PERS_ID,
dbo.STUDIESTARTER.STUDST_ID,
dbo.Optagelse_Studiestatus.AFGANGSARSAG,
dbo.Optagelse_Studiestatus.KORT_BETEGNELSE,
dbo.STUDIESTARTER.OPTAG_START_MANED,
Studiestatus,
dbo.ANSOGNINGER.ANSOG_ID,
dbo.ANSOGNINGER.ANKOMSTDATO,
dbo.ANSOGNINGER.EFTEROPTAG,
dbo.ANSOGNINGER.STATUSDATO
```

I really hope somebody out there can help.

Comment: Please edit your question and show a minimal query.  Include your current and expected output as _text_ within your question.

Comment: you seem to be new here,I recommend going through below link (spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/…) to know more on how to ask questions,you will get a faster response and in the long run it will help you a lot

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I will edit it tommorow, when I have time.

Comment: And remove "top 100 percent" - that does not do anything useful. And since your query has no aggregates but does have a group by clause, you appear to have written a query that is logically flawed. This appears to be the reason you are using a group by clause - to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways, this will work:

```
WITH subSource AS (
/* Your query here */
)
SELECT
  s1.id,
  /* all other columns work like this: 
     COALESCE(S1.column,s2.column)
     for example: */
  coalesce(s1.appid,s2.appid) as appid
FROM subSource s1
INNER JOIN subSource s2
ON s1.study_id =s2.study_id 
  and s1.study_start = s2.study_start 
  AND s1.id > s2.id
  /* I imagine some other clauses might be needed but maybe not */
```

The rest is copy paste

Comment: Thank you very much! I look forward to trying this out tommorow. I will accept the answer after I have tried it.